# how to hide times from fullcalendar other than businessHours

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am working on fullcalendar plugin. I am facing an issue hiding other times than businessHours. My Calendar starts with 12 AM and i want to start it from the businessHour lets say, 10:00 AM to 07:00 PM
            i also want to know can we reload fullcalendar. I have to give choice if user want to see in timeSlot of 15 mins or 30 mins Whenever user clicks on that fullcalendar needs to be reloaded with the setting done by user.

Please help me fixing these.

Thanks,
Amod

Comment: You would help out potential answerers quite a lot if you could make a JSFiddle with how far you've gotten until now.

Comment: @leroydev Thank you for the reply. I have done that using minTime and maxTime. It worked and setting height:auto